# Secure data transfer

Tags: security, transfer

I need some advice regarding website security.

I have a website application where a user enters their details in a form, the data is then transmitted to a third party website using a POST request and SSL for encryption.

Is there anything else I can do to secure the data that's being transmitted? Please let me know if you need any more specific details.

Comment: the question would be, is your website also running over HTTPS? if yes, you should be safe :)

Answer (score 1):

If by 'secure' you mean not readable by any others except that third party, SSL would be enough. But if you mean you do not even want that third party read that posted data, you should encrypt it before post it to the third party.

Comment: thanks for your response, that is what I mean, that only the third party should be able to read it. I just wasn't sure if there was additional security I could add to the page that contains the form to stop other people seeing the form data.